# How can I limit the usage of swap memory in k8s?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I know k8s does not support swap by default.

But since I have a rather static deployment of pods in k8s (3 nodes, each with a solr + zookeeper pod), so I decided to set up 2G swap on all my worker nodes anyway and allow the use of swap by starting **kubelet** with --`fail-swap-on=false`

Now I have got the cluster up & running, and it seemed to be running okay.

However, I found that my java processes are using a lot of swap, I am worried that this might affect the performance.

- RSS: 317160 Kb
- SWAP: 273232 Kb

My question is that is there a way to limit the use of swap memory usage by containers?

I was thinking about setting `--memory-swap` [params of Docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details)

Currently, based on Docker inspect my container has no limit on swap usage ( `"MemorySwap": -1` )

```
sudo docker inspect 482d70f73c7c | grep Memory
            "Memory": 671088640,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": -1,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
```

But I just couldn't find this param exposed in k8s.

**My vm-related settings**

```
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
vm.swappiness = 20
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 1000
```

p.s. Will the **limit** on pod memory also limit the swap usage?

Thank you all for reading the post!

### Notes

This is how I got the RSS & SWAP of my Java process

**Run** `top`

`27137 8983      20   0 3624720 317160      0 S   3.0 32.0   4:06.74 java`

**Run**

```
find /proc -maxdepth 2 -path "/proc/[0-9]*/status" -readable -exec awk -v FS=":" '{process[$1]=$2;sub(/^[ \t]+/,"",process[$1]);} END {if(process["VmSwap"] && process["VmSwap"] != "0 kB") printf "%10s %-30s %20s\n",process["Pid"],process["Name"],process["VmSwap"]}' '{}' \; | awk '{print $(NF-1),$0}' | sort -h | cut -d " " -f2-
```

`27137 java                                      273232 kB`

Answer (score 2):

And now you know why the kubelet literally refuses to start by default if there swap active. This is not exposed anywhere in CRI and won’t be.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I know I might encounter some trouble by enabling it so I only enabled it because my deployment is rather static.

And after a few experiments, I think I found a k8s issue.

It seems that on some platform, k8s will allow unlimited MemorySwap for containers

See: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53533#issuecomment-598027926

Comment: @JohntheTraveler just an addition: no, the pod memory limit does not set a limit on swap

Comment: K8s as both a project and an ecosystem just pretends swap does not exist at all :)